# Docker plugin - passing and storing passwords in a standalone docker setup

Tags: security, docker, plugins

I'm working on a docker plugin that needs to access an external service using a password. The password should be configured at plugin install time and be available during the plugin's lifetime.

Currently I'm using env variables, optionally reading the password from a file via `VAR=$(cat password_file)`. This approach is convenient, but doesn't seem like a very good solution as the password can be looked up using `docker plugin inspect`.

I wonder what would be the best way to pass and store passwords in a plugin using standalone docker setup. Swarm and Kubernetes (and probably other orchestration solutions) support secrets. Unfortunately, standalone docker doesn't seem to support secrets and the customer's docker setup is not under my controls :-(

I did look through the documentation and spent time googling the answer, but came up empty. In fact, I saw a few generic threads about storing passwords in containers with no satisfactory answers, but these were from a few years ago and I was hoping that maybe in 2018 such a basic issue has a decent solution.

P.S. This is my first question - please be gentle with me.